# How can I reset text input values to the old values, after disabled input fields in a form after button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, blazor

I have the following code:

```
<form id="formexample">
<div class="row g-5">
  <div class="col">
    <h5><strong>Informations</strong></h5>
    <br />
    <label class="form-label" for="">Sample Value</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="@isDisabled"
      @bind="@binded_value" @oninput="@((e) => { binded_value=(string)e.Value!;})" placeholder="" style="margin-bottom:1rem">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Remarks on the tool concept</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="@isDisabled"
      @bind="@second_binded_value" @oninput="@((e) => { second_binded_value=(string)e.Value!;})" placeholder="" style="margin-bottom:1rem">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to show the binded values, when I click on a button, that allows me to disable the textfield in the form. When I change the binded values manually, the new values are still shown after the form is disabled and not available for any changes. I hope the description of the problem is accurate enough.

Comment: If I understand correctly, after a button click, you want the `input` to be disabled without any values inside while the values that you wrote are shown somewhere else.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the description correctly. If you are asking to show the old values when the edit form is disabled on the button click, then you need to keep the original values either in a variable or in a user-defined model. When disabling, you can read from the source and reassign them to **binded_value** and **second_binded_value**.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I have a form and I can show/disable the input fields with edit and cancel edit buttons. The text input fields of the form show binded values. But when a user wants to edit the form and overwrites the binded values and cancels the edit after (all fields are disabled then), then the edited fields show me the overwrited values from the user. And my question is, how can i revert the values when I click on cancel

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal that seems like a good solution, will try it, thank you!

Comment: @C.Oezer, yes, you could simply use a second set of variables. However, it does not seem there is a security matter here but, a user can easily remove `disabled` from an input. You could need some additional security when you don't want an input to be used or modified.